# How can I repeat a string N times in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, operators, repeat

In Python, if I do this:

```
print "4" * 4
```

I get

```
> "4444"
```

In Perl, I'd get

```
> 16
```

Is there an easy way to do the former in Perl?

Comment: This is also possible with string variables (and string expressions), see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30100928/2932052).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
$ perl -e 'print "4" x 4; print "\n"'
4444
```

The x operator is documented in perldoc [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). Here binary means an operator taking two arguments, not composed of bits, by the way.

> Binary "x" is the repetition operator. In scalar context or if the
> left operand is not enclosed in parentheses, it returns a string consisting
> of the left operand repeated the number of times specified by the right
> operand. In list context, if the left operand is enclosed in parentheses
> or is a list formed by "`qw/STRING/`", it repeats the list. If the right
> operand is zero or negative, it returns an empty string or an empty
> list, depending on the context.

```
       print '-' x 80;             # Print row of dashes

       print "\t" x ($tab/8), ' ' x ($tab%8);      # Tab over

       @ones = (1) x 80;           # A list of 80 1’s
       @ones = (5) x @ones;        # Set all elements to 5
```

`perl -e` is meant to execute Perl code from the command line:

```
$ perl --help
Usage: perl [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]
  
  -e program     one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
```

Comment: Just a remark - it may not be clear to all perl users (especially the new ones) what the -e option does, so it would be better to provide direct code example (as Paul's response does).

Comment: `perl -Esay+4x4` Here, '-E' enables 'use 5.010' (particularly - the 'say' feature). `say "$var"` is the same as `print "$var\n"`. In scalar context the 'x' operator always returns a string, so there is no need to use quotes here.

Comment: Now that would be confusing :-)

Comment: And no reason to use double quotes, to pile on the picky.

Comment: I would like to see the reason, for the differences, to be cited in this answer. The reason is that, in Perl you can treat a string as a number, and it will automatically become a number.

Comment: I have a reason to use quotes, readability and intent. The fact you can omit them doesn't mean you have to (or even should).

Answer (score 45):

In Perl, you want to use the "x" operator.

Note the difference between

```
"4" x 4
```

and

```
("4") x 4
```

The former produces a repeated string:

```
"4444"
```

the latter a repeated list:

```
("4", "4", "4", "4")
```

Comment: In Perl 6 the `x` operator always returns string (left operand is evaluated in a string context e.g., 4x4 -> "4"x4 -> "4444"), `xx` - a repeat op for lists e.g., 4xx4 -> (4)xx4 -> (4,4,4,4).

Comment: I cannot confirm that for Perl v5.32

Answer (score 17):

It's very similar in Perl

```
print "4" x 4;
```

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, it’s also `print 4 x 4` in Perl.

In general, in Perl, operators are monomorphic, ie. you have different sets of operators for string semantics, for numeric semantics, for bitwise semantics, etc., where it makes sense, and the type of the operands largely doesn’t matter. When you apply a numeric operator to a string, the string is converted to a number first and you get the operation you asked for (eg. multiplication), and when you apply a string operator to a number, it’s turned into a string and you get the operation you asked for (eg. repetition). Perl pays attention to the operator first and the types of the operands only second – if indeed it pays them any mind at all.

This is the opposite of Python and most other languages, where you use one set of operators, and the types of the operands determine which semantics you’ll actually get – ie. operators are polymorphic.

Comment: The fact you can doesn't mean you should, necessarily. I think that making intentions clear makes the code more readable for everybody. Omitting quotes makes it less readable to my eyes.

Comment: a) Did you see anything in my answer about what you should or should not do? (This `4 x 4` is unlikely to show up in real Perl code verbatim anyway.) b) If it is less readable to you, you are paying attention to the wrong things (the forms of the operands, rather than the operator).

Comment: a) Did you see anything in my comment about whether you said what one should or should not do? b) When you deal with many languages on almost a daily basis, every little bit helps. Using quotes is totally clear an unambiguous in (almost) any language, omitting them means one extra mental step to take.

Answer (score 2):

All answers, given so far, missed mentioning that the operator `x` does not only work on string *literals*, but also on variables that *are* strings or expressions that *evaluate* to strings like

```
use feature 'say';

my $msg = "hello ";
say $msg x 2;
say chr(33) x 3;
```

like this

```
hello hello
!!!
```

and, **even more important**, `x` does an **automatic conversion** of expressions into strings if they aren't already (thanks to [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30100928/timeline#comment_125504067) for pointing me into that direction!). So for example

```
say 4 x 2;
say [$msg] x 2;
```

will result in something like the following as output

```
44
ARRAY(0x30ca10)ARRAY(0x30ca10)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print 10 character "A"s, you can also do this

```
perl -e 'print "A" x 10'; echo
```

Example with output

```
user@linux:~$ perl -e 'print "A" x 10'; echo
AAAAAAAAAA
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: How is this different from the previous answers?