# How do I repeat a character n times in a string used inside a regular expression substitution?

Tags: perl

How do I repeat a character n times in a string used in substitution?

I want to do something like below:

```
$numOfChar = 10;

s/^\s*(.*)/' ' x $numOfChar$1/;
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Note: Not really *[How can I repeat a string N times in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277485/)* (the search engines can't tell the difference), as this question is about repetition inside a regular expression (or substitution, rather).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By default, substitutions take a string as the part to substitute. To execute code in the substitution process you have to use the `e` flag.

```
$numOfChar = 10;

s/^(.*)/' ' x $numOfChar . $1/e;
```

This will add `$numOfChar` space to the start of your text. To do it for every line in the text either use the `-p` flag (for quick, one-line processing):

```
cat foo.txt | perl -p -e "$n = 10; s/^(.*)/' ' x $n . $1/e/" > bar.txt
```

or if  it's a part of a larger script use the `-g` and `-m` flags (`-g` for global, i.e. repeated substitution and `-m` to make `^` match at the start of each line):

```
$n = 10;
$text =~ s/^(.*)/' ' x $n . $1/mge;
```

Answer (score 15):

Your regular expression can be written as:

```
$numOfChar = 10;

s/^(.*)/(' ' x $numOfChar).$1/e;
```

but - you can do it with:

```
s/^/' ' x $numOfChar/e;
```

Or without using regexps at all:

```
$_ = ( ' ' x $numOfChar ) . $_;
```

Comment: Note that this answer no longer applies, because chappar added a \s* to his question after this answer was given.

Comment: At the moment none of the answers really apply.

But it can be easily fixed.

Just change:

  s/^/' ' x $numOfChar/e;

into:

  s/^\s*/' ' x $numOfChar/e;

Answer (score 9):

You're right. Perl's `x` operator repeats a string a number of times.

```
print "test\n" x 10; # prints 10 lines of "test"
```

To do this inside a regular expression, it would probably be best (a.k.a. most maintainer friendly) to just assign the value to another variable.

```
my $spaces = " " x 10;
s/^\s*(.*)/$spaces$1/;
```

There are ways to do it without an extra variable, but it's just my $0.02 that it'll be easier to maintain if you do it this way.

Comment: That didn't work. I think it works only inside print statement

Comment: I am trying something like this. s/^(.*)/'p' x $numOfChar/; I have modified my question