# How to have Perl repeat the entire sentence with each variable

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
@no = (1 .. 20000);
foreach(@no) {
    print "<div id=\"world@no\" onclick=\"javascript:showDiv_postscreen(); javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()\">&nbsp;</div>\n";
}
```

This is my Perl script, but how do I get it to rewrite the sentence with a new variable each time?

I.e., how do I get it to output the following?

```html
<div id="world1" onclick="javascript:showDiv_postscreen(); javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()">&nbsp;</div>
.
.
.
<div id="world20000" onclick="javascript:showDiv_postscreen(); javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Note: Not to be confused with *[How can I repeat a string N times in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277485/)* (the search engines can't tell the difference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@` in the print statement is confusing the interpreter.  Also, it isn't what you want, since `print "@no"` would print out the same thing as `join(' ',@no)`.  Instead, you want to interpolate each element of `@no` into the string that's printed out:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings; #Always use these!
my @no = (1 .. 20000); 
foreach(@no) { 
print "<div id=\"world" . $_ . "\" onclick=\"javascript:showDiv_postscreen(); javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()\">&nbsp;</div>\n"; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is interpolating the whole array into your string instead of the loop variable (`$_` in your case since you didn't specify one, but I prefer to give it a name).

You can avoid needing to escape the `"`s by using a different delimiter for your string:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
for my $world_no (1..20000) {
    print qq!<div id="world$world_no" onclick="showDiv_postscreen(); hideDiv_welcomebuttons()">&nbsp;</div>\n!;
}
```

Also, the "javascript:" is only necessary for things like `<a href="...">` where a url is expected and you want to supply javascript code instead.  It's not needed for onclick, certainly not twice.

Comment: At least one answer makes like easier. We need those backslashes so don't waste them. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
my @no = (1 .. 20000); 
foreach my $i (@no) { 
    print "<div id=\"world$i\" onclick=\"javascript:showDiv_postscreen(); javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()\">&nbsp;</div>\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Why not just use: `foreach my $i (1 .. 20_000)`, otherwise you are loosing memory to prelocate the array size

Comment: @Dimi Or `for (my $i = 1; $i <= 20_000; $i++)` to avoid loading any memory. ;) Or a while loop, like in my answer.

Comment: This is the example, in real program array may be created some other way, not every number.

Comment: @TLP: That's also a solution, however I just dont like that syntax ;) Alexandr: My point was that you don't need to create the array at all, because you allocate memory for 20_000 elements.

Comment: TLP: for(;;) doesn't save any memory over for(..)

Comment: @ysth You mean that it still extrapolates into a list before the loop begins?

Comment: @ysth You may wish to have a chat with Chas. He seems to think that it does. Do you mean to say that `for (...)` does not expand its arguments into a list before the loop begins?

Comment: @TLP: specifically for over a range operator

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
@no = (1 .. 20);
foreach $x (@no) {
print "<div id=\"world$x\" onclick=\"javascript:showDiv_postscreen()\;javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()\">&nbsp;</div>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a variable to count, instead of defining a range. It may feel less intuitive, but it is not.

Also, instead of escaping the double quotes (`\"`), you can use `qq()`, which is equivalent.

```
my $i = 1;
print qq(<div id="world$i" onclick="javascript:showDiv_postscreen(); javascript:hideDiv_welcomebuttons()">&nbsp;</div>\n) while ($i++ <= 20_000);
```