# Perl: Repeat a pattern x times, where x is a match of \d

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have matched a certain pattern and additionally a number via

```
perl -pe 's/\(pattern\)(\d)/ ... /'
```

I know that I can access the pattern by putting $1 where the ... are and the number by using $2. How can I now repeat pattern $2 times where the ... are?
To be more specific, I have an expression like:

```
perl -pe 'while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),2\)/(($1)*($1))/){}' file.txt
```

And I want to generalize this to not only match the 2, which is hardcoded in there to repeat $1 twice, but to match any number n and repeat $1 n times. All of this should still be done in a oneliner.

So for example calling the script onto expressions like

```
Power(Power(x,3),2)
```

should return

```
(((x)*(x)*(x))*((x)*(x)*(x)))
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner?

Comment: A few examples of inputs/outputs would be helpful.

Comment: @stark technically it does not need to be, but it would be the easiest for me to implement into my existing script.
@ Dada I will add some to the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
perl -pe 'while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),(\d+)\)/"((". $1 . ")" . ("*(" . $1 . ")") x ($2-1) . ")"/e){}' file.txt
```

See the online demo:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Power(25,2)  Power(225,4)'
perl -pe 'while(s/Power\(((?:(?!Power\().)+?),(\d+)\)/"((". $1 . ")" . ("*(" . $1 . ")") x ($2-1) . ")"/e){}' <<< "$s"
# => ((25)*(25))  ((225)*(225)*(225)*(225))
```

The `/e` flag treats the RHS as an expression, the replacement is built dynamically, and the repetitions are made with the help of the [`x` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/277485/3832970). Note that the repetition amount is equal to the number captured into Group 2 minus `1`.